# Is there a way to programatically find EventLogs and the Windows Services that generated them?

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services, event-log, servicecontroller

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2019. I'm trying to get to list of all Windows Services currently on the system, which I successfully got, then get the EventLogs associated with those services, which I haven't been able to.

I'm able to get all services, I'm able to get all event logs.

```
    ServiceController[] all = ServiceController.GetServices();
    foreach (ServiceController item in all)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ServiceName);
        Console.WriteLine(item.DisplayName);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
    }
    EventLog[] eventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
```

I've been trying to find some way to connect the two but I'm not coming up with anything meaningful.

I was hoping to find a way to map service-to-log or log-to-service.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: An `EventLog` can have multiple sources. Have you tried to use the `EventLogEntry.Source` property of the log entries (`EventLog.Entries`)?

Comment: @dymanoid Yes, I look in there but found no entries linking back to the services. Either that, or I'm missing something critical.. I feel I'm so close to getting it

Comment: You might need to use ```System``` as a source. Most of the services run in System user.